# After parsing from xml display data randomly using j query and html5

Tags: jquery, xml, html

Hello I am newbie in HTML5 and j query. I have to parse data from XML that i have done successfully. After parsing data now I want to display it randomly using j query.Please  suggest me how do I do this.

The code snippet is

```
 // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","xml/multiquestions1.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;     

    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("question");
    $(document).ready(function (){
        for(var j=0;j<x.length;j++)
        {
            if(j==0)
            {
                $("#navigationlist").append('<li><a href="#" id="selected_link"  class="navg" onClick="display_nav('+j+',this);">'+(j+1)+'</a></li>');   
                display_nav(j,$("#selected_link"))
            }
            else
                $("#navigationlist").append('<li><a href="#" class="navg" onClick="display_nav('+j+',this);">'+(j+1)+'</a></li>');   
        }               
    });

function display()
    {
        // for fetch question
        Description=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("questionTxt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        Answer =(x[j].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

        document.getElementById('options').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+Answer+')';

        // Assign the value
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML= Description; 

    }   

function display_nav(j,obj)
    {
       i=j;
       $("#feedback").html(""); 
        $(".navg").each(function(){

           $(this).removeAttr("id");                         
        });

        $(obj).attr("id","selected_link");
        Description=(x[j].getElementsByTagName("questionTxt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        Answer =(x[j].getElementsByTagName("image")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        answermin=(x[j].getElementsByTagName("answermin")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        answermax=(x[j].getElementsByTagName("answermax")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

        $("#bob").attr("min",answermin);
        $("#bob").attr("max",answermax);
        $("#bob").attr("value",0);
        $("#out").html(0);
        $("#out").css({left:0});

        // Assign the value
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML= Description;
        //document.getElementById("options").style.backgroundImage = url(Answer);
        document.getElementById('options').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+Answer+')';       
    }   

and xml is

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FlashCards>
  <question id="1">
    <questionTxt type="text"><![CDATA[Hello!]]></questionTxt>
<image visible="true"><![CDATA[img/smiley1.png]]></image>
    </question>  
 <question id="2">
    <questionTxt type="text"><![CDATA[Hi]]></questionTxt>
<image visible="true"><![CDATA[img/smiley2.png]]></image>

</question> 
</FlashCards>
```

Comment: since you use jquery you should use it on everything. Like `getElementsByTagName, getElementById`, even the whole `xmlhttp` part is not needed. It'll save you a lot of typing and pain.

Comment: didn't get :(. Can u elaborate where should I do the changes?

Comment: 1. for instance your whole request in the beginning can be done with a simple: `$.get()`, `getElementsByTagName` can be replaced by `$('tagName')`, `getElementById` by `$('#idName')` ... You should dig deeper into jQuery.
2. the code you posted looks quite complicated, not many people want to dig through and find the mistake. You should reduce it to whats really needed. Also Variables like i, j, s, x are not so useful. It takes a lot of time to find out what they are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery comes with its own parsing function `jQuery.parseXML()` -> [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Then you can do searches ontop of the parsed xml more easier.

```
var xml = $.parseXML(xmlString),
    // find and count all questions
    questionCount = xml.find('question').length();
// find a random question out of the pool
xml.find('question#'+ Math.floor(Math.random() * (questionCount + 1))):
```

I didn't test it, but I hope you get the point.